Certain devices marked as "Not Supported" in Google Play Device Catalog (e.g., Samsung Galaxy S9+)
I'm facing an issue with my Android app on the Google Play Store, where certain devices appear as "Not Supported" in the Device Catalog. One example is the Samsung Galaxy S9+. I'm trying to make the app available to all mobile phones, but I want to avoid desktops, tablets, and similar non-mobile devices.
Here’s my AndroidManifest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <compatible-screens>
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />

        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xxhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

I've included a  section to target only certain screen sizes and densities, but it seems to exclude more devices than expected, including many mobile phones. I don't want my app to be available on Android desktops, tablets, etc., but I need it accessible on all standard mobile phones.
Questions:
Why might certain phones like the Samsung Galaxy S9+ be marked as Not Supported?
Is there a better way to restrict my app to mobile phones only, without explicitly listing screen sizes and densities, which seems too restrictive?
Any insights on how to resolve this are much appreciated!
